# c# tcp server browser sometimes send extra data into buffer in multipart file upload

Tags: c#, sockets, multipart

sometimes my multipart section of my webserver recieves additional data
for example add some binary data in middle of file.
this is code of this part:

```
string content = "";

content = sBuffer;                                                
int boundaryContentStart = content.IndexOf("boundary=") + "boundary=".Length;
string boundary = content.Substring(boundaryContentStart, content.Length - boundaryContentStart - "boundary=".Length);                                                
string boundarSeprator = boundary.Remove(boundary.IndexOf("\r\n"));

string temp = sBuffer;

while (!content.Contains(boundarSeprator + "--"))
{
    mySocket.Receive(bReceive, bReceive.Length, 0);

    temp = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(bReceive);
    content += temp;

    temp = "";
}
```

sBuffer is my string recieve buffer which is 1024 byte array
why this happens and sometimes browser sends extra information in middle of file part in multipart form post.

whole content is added to conetent variable as you see in code above.

**remember** this not always happens. just sometimes wreck my files
is that a mechanism that browser sometimes resend some part of data to server that I dont know?
mySocket is a tcp socket.
thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are ignoring the return value of `mySocket.Receive(bReceive, bReceive.Length, 0);` which indicates the number of bytes actually written to the buffer by the read, you will therefore be re-reading data left in the buffer from a previous read when `Receive` reads less than `bReceive.Length` bytes.

You should instead store the return value from `Receive` in a local variable, and use the overload of `GetString` that accepts a start and length (passing it as the length parameter).

You should also check if the receive reads 0 bytes, indicating the connection has been closed, otherwise your code will enter an infinite loop it the other side closes the connection without sending the expected data.

Finally, depending on the amount of data you're expecting, you might want to rethink how you search for the boundary separator on the received content. If we assume the content to be 1MB, and it gets received in 1KB chunks, your `content.Contains` will first be run over 1KB, then 2KB, 3KB, etc. by the time the whole 1MB has been read, you will effectively have performed `Contains` over about 500MB of data. Similarly, the repeated concatenation of the received data to `content` is rather inefficient as a new string is created, requiring all of the data to be copied each time.

Comment: You beat me to it. Always the same issue.

Comment: @usr I can't find a clean reference question on this (indeed frequently-occurring) issue to close this one as a duplicate of. Do you know of any?

Comment: thanks for reply.ok. I change my code and I think it will work. if I get success I set your answer accepted.what about concatenation?what alternative I have to change that?

Comment: thanks so so so much.I changed my code and post it here hope others can use it, and added stopwatch for performance. when we use bigger size for btt array (socket buffer) , speed gets more faster. can test it

Comment: Stopwatch sw1 = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

string temp = sBuffer;

while (!content.Contains(boundarSeprator + "--"))
{                                                    
    byte[] btt = new byte[10240];
    //mySocket.Receive(bReceive, bReceive.Length, 0);
    int i= mySocket.Receive(btt, btt.Length, 0);

    //temp = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(btt);
    temp = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(btt,0,i);
    content += temp;
    temp = "";
    temp = string.Empty;                                  
}
sw1.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("upload time: "+sw1.Elapsed);

Comment: @CodeCaster in my answer/comment history you'll find about 100 partial duplicates. But you can never be sure that this is the only problem. In fact, it rarely is...

Comment: My problem solved. but have another quesion. when working with 1024 buffer items ok in lan but in interet recieves parts half. but when increase buffer size 1024*10 in internet problem solved too